# Restriction of complex polynomial that is a covering map

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, covering-spaces

In my book the following exercise is given:
let $p(z)\in \mathbb{C}[z]$ be a complex polynomial with distinct roots and degree $n>1$. Determine the greatest neighborhood $V$ of 0 such that $p:p^{-1}(V)\to V$ is a covering map.

My attempt of solution: I've shown, using inverse function theorem, that, if $Y:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: p'(z)=0\}$ and $U:=\mathbb{C}\setminus p^{-1}(p(Y))$, then $p:U \to p(U)$ is a covering map. Unfortunately there exist polynomials $p$ such that $p'(0)=0$. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm thinking something along this line. The condition that $p$ has distinct roots here is crucial, i.e, if, say, $z_i$'s are the zeros of $p$, then $p'(z_i)\neq 0$. And thus, $0$ will be a regular value. Then we can say that around each $z_i$, $p$ will be a local diffeomorphism - that is, if $D$ is any open disk around $0$, then $f^{-1}(D)$ is the countable union of disjoint open disks $D_i$ around each $z_i$ such that $f|_{D_i}$ is a diffeomorphism. Then I think we can show $p:p^{-1}(D)\rightarrow D$ is a covering map. If this is true for any $D$, then the largest set should be $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Inverse function theorem assures only that exists an open disc $D$ around 0 such that $p:p^{-1}(D)\to D$ is a covering map. This is not true for every open disk $D$ around 0. If you take $D=\mathbb{C}$ then $p^{-1}(D)=\mathbb{C}$, and you are saying that $p:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a covering map, which is in general false, even if the roots of $p$ are distinct.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Good catch. So what would happen when we take the union of all such open disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic points for local inversion are the *critical values* of $p$, namely the points of the set $C = \{p(z) : p'(z) = 0\}$. Therefore, the largest open set covered by $p$ is $V = \mathbb C\setminus C$.  We have $0\in V$ because if $0\in C$, that means $p(z)=0=p'(z)$ for some $z$, contradicting the assumption that the roots are distinct.